# GIT - Notify the author of a tagged line of code

Tags: git, hook, commit, notify, author

I just got a new job as a developer and going through lots of unfamiliar code I often wonder how it works or if maybe there is a bug but I don't want to ask my coworkers every single time and keeping notes of everything also seems a bit time consuming.

So I was wondering, is there a way that maybe I could put a comment above the line of code I find unclear/buggy/etc and when I push, the author of that line would be notified through slack/email and would have to have a look at the code and check if the concerns mentioned in the comment are valid?

I assume some form of regex/hooks combination would be necessary, right?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: git don't have such feature, what you need is a integrated product like github

Answer (score 0):

You can surely achieve this with post-commit hooks. But I think the better solution would be some code-review tool like Gerrit, oder GitHub Enterprise, or Collaborator.